# ArcGIS for server install guides documentation PDF?

Tags: arcgis-server, documentation

ESRI has [install guides](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/welcome-to-the-arcgis-for-server-install-guide.htm) online which I would like to print and keep on file as a PDF.  I could create a PDF from each step then bind these together but it seems like a lengthy and cumbersome process.

Any ideas where I can obtain a PDF of the install guides?

Comment: good question related is https://twitter.com/mapperz/status/735923435742728192 to esri - seems they cannot make a website anymore like the old help (useful)

Answer (score 1):

If you would be OK with having these files as HTML instead of PDF for your archive, they do come with the installer. When you unpack the setup file, look in the folder where it unpacks to. For me, it is C:\Users\myusername\Documents\ArcGISxxx\Server. In this folder, look under SetupFiles\Documentation. This should be a mirror image of the online docs, but stored locally on your machine.

Comment: After you have your hands on these PDFs, you could always use something like Pandoc to convert PDF to HTML.